# Run tests on different devices using Appium in parallel mode

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios

So, is it possible to run one test on different devices with different OS (on android and ios) using one Appium server instance? Or I need to up different Appium instances on different ports?

I can't found any information about devices that work on different systems, only for the same one (f.e. 2 android devices or 2 ios).

Thanks!

Comment: Open Multiple Insatnces of Appium and Use different port and host in Appium server.
please check on forum : https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-run-appium-test-on-multiple-devices/17795/2

Comment: here is more help : https://discuss.appium.io/t/alternative-to-selenium-grid-for-running-appium-tests-in-parallel/18025